# Scalar nonlinear balance law with non-integrable source term on a bounded domain

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde

I am considering the following PDE for $(t,x)\in\mathbb R_+\times[0,1]$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u(t,x) + \partial_x[u(1-u)]=G(x,u),\\
u(0,\cdot)=u_0, \quad u(\cdot,0)=\alpha, \quad u(\cdot,1)=\beta,
\end{cases}
$$
where

- the source term $G$ is given by
  $$
  G=\frac{\alpha-u}{x^\gamma}+\frac{\beta-u}{(1-x)^\gamma}, \quad \gamma\ge1,
  $$
- $\alpha$, $\beta$ are constants,
- $u_0 \in L^\infty(0,1)$ (it is fine to assume $u_0$ is smooth or BV, with any necessary compatibility).

**My question: how to define the "entropy solution" and more importantly, can we get uniqueness / stability on initial data?**

---

I tried the vanishing viscosity method (Section 2.6 - 2.8 of [1]).
For $\varepsilon>0$, take the solution of the parabolic problem (let's assume $u_0$ is smooth):
$$
\begin{cases}\partial_t u^\varepsilon(t,x) + \partial_x[u^\varepsilon(1-u^\varepsilon)]=G(x,u^\varepsilon),\\
u^\varepsilon(0,\cdot)=u_0, \quad u^\varepsilon(\cdot,0)=\alpha, \quad u^\varepsilon(\cdot,1)=\beta.
\end{cases}
$$
Then take $\varepsilon\to0$ to obtain (subsequential) limit $u \in L^\infty(\mathbb R_+\times(0,1)$.
For any $T<\infty$, $u$ satisfies the energy bound
$$
\label{1}\tag{$*$}\iint\limits_{(0,T)\times(0,1)} \frac{(u-\alpha)^2}{x^\gamma}+\frac{(u-\beta)^2}{(1-x)^\gamma} dxdt<\infty,$$

as well as the generalised entropy inequality:

$$\label{2}\tag{$**$}\iint [f(u)\partial_t\psi + q(u)\partial_x\psi + G(x,u)f'(u)\psi] dxdt + \int f(u_0)\psi(0,\cdot)dx \ge 0$$

for any Lax entropy pair $(f,q)$: $f''\ge0$, $q'(u)=(1-2u)f'(u)$ and any $\psi \in C_0^\infty((-\infty,T)\times\mathbb R)$ such that $\psi\ge0$ and

$$\iint\limits_{(0,T)\times(0,1)} \psi^2(t,x)[x^{-\gamma}+(1-x)^{-\gamma}]dxdt<\infty.$$

Intuitively, \eqref{2} contains the initial data and also tells me how the solution should behave inside $(0,1)$, while \eqref{1} controls the behavior near the boundaries (because $\gamma$ is large).
But I am not sure if they are enough to obtain uniqueness.

**Reference**

[1] Jindřich Nečas, Josef Málek, Mirko Rokyta, Michael Růžička, *Weak and measure-valued solutions to evolutionary PDEs*, Applied Mathematics and Mathematical Computation. 13. London: Chapman & Hall, pp. vii+317 (1996), ISBN:0-412-57750-X, [MR1409366](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1409366), [Zbl 0851.35002](https://zbmath.org/0851.35002).